# useState hook to keep track selected item - delay in updating after third/fourth click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Below is the snippet of my implementation to keep track on my selected tab item. Everything seems to be working fine but somehow on third/fourth click or sometimes fifth click, it loses track and not updating and then a few clicks later, it works fine again...

```
const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = React.useState("tab-1");
const handleClick = React.useCallback((id) => {
    setSelectedTab(id);
}, []);
const isTabOne = selectedTab === "tab-1";
const tabsData = [
    {
        id: "tab-1",
        headerNode: (
            <>
                <span onClick={() => handleClick("tab-1")}>Tab 1</span>
            </>
        ),
        contentNode: (
            <div>
                tab one content
            </div>
        ),
    },
    {
        id: "tab-2",
        contentNode: (
            <>
                <span onClick={() => handleClick("tab-2")}>Tab 2</span>
            </>
        ),
        tabPanelNode: (
            <div>
                tab two content
            </div>
        ),
    },
];
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @Medi yes because it's only two. I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: How are you rendering the tabs? What are the conditions you put?

Comment: Why are you using useCallback for handle click event?

Comment: @lissettdm after a few tries trying to figure out this. I decided to follow this approach, hence the useCallback - https://dev.to/alexkhismatulin/update-boolean-state-right-with-react-hooks-3k2i

Comment: I don't see any reason to use usCallback here. I think that this <span onClick={() => setSelectedTab("tab-2")}>Tab 2</span> will do the job....How are you painting tabsData?

Comment: The tabsData is rendered in its own component and being called like so without any condition in the above(parent component) - `<Tabs  tabs={tabsData} />` I'm testing it by clicking back and forth and first few clicks working seamlessly but after a while (fourth/fifth click) it stops updating.